# What's the difference between the 3 commands: Exit-PSSession , Exit-PSHostProcess and Exit in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, exit

I start to lean PowerShell this year, and I have some confusion about the PowerShell commands:
Exit-PSSession , Exit-PSHostProcess and Exit. Could anyone expert to help me to understand these commands,
if another PowerShell script is running, after using "Exit", does it end all the PowerShell scripts including running script?

Thanks a lot!

code example is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The two exit commands are used to close the equivalent start commands.  Exit is the normal return method in PS that allows you to terminate a script and return an exit code.